# how to deal with exceptions for every method in a class

Tags: java, design-patterns

I hava a class, i need add try catch for every method, but it looks redundant, so i need a good way to fix it, what kind of design pattern can solve this?

```
public class Test {
    public void a() {
        try {
            do something;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error happened");
        }
    }

    public void b() {
        try {
            do something;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error happened");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you think you **need** to add a try/catch for every method ? Shouldn't some method only throws the exception ? Why do you think only a design pattern can solve this ? Can you provide more explicit code (insteand of `do something`) ?

Answer (score 1):

If your do something have just the same values need for try catch, then you can put it this way

```
public class Test {
    public void a() {
        //do other stuffs that don't require try catch and different from b
        c(); //pass some values if you need too
    }

    public void b() {
        //do other stuffs that don't require try catch and different from a
        c(); //pass some values if you need too
    }

    public void c() { //catch values if you pass something from a and b
        try {
            do something;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error happened");
        }
    }//put return if you like.
}
```

but if you have different do something and try catch value for each method, you really have to do it that way.

Comment: every method do different thing

Comment: if you have different methods, you can't put them in one method. unless they have something in common :) . or else do an inner exception which will just give a more try catch statement but more cleaner :)

Answer (score 1):

One of practical solutions is to use frameworks such as [spring ExceptionHandler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Essentially you use `throws SomeException` in lower layers of your application and catch everything in top layer

Controller:

```
  @ExceptionHandler({SQLException.class,DataAccessException.class})
  public String databaseError() {
    return "databaseError";
  }
```

Layers below:

```
public void doStufff throws SQLexception{
    // do stuff which may throw exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not try to catch the exception outside the method?

you need only to make sure what exception will throw from this method

eg:

```
Test a = new Test();

try {
    a.a();
    a.b();
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("error happened");
}
```

Comment: it seems you do not get my point, i need to know how to deal with exceptions for every method in a class, such as spring aop, but i do not want to use spring.

Comment: I think `exceptions` will not be `Exception`, every different exception should have different catcher. And methods need only to throw it out. I don't know if this is a good  practice

Answer (score 0):

You can do some of this with an "Execute around" idiom, but it wont save you much boilerplate. The following wont quite work - you'll need to a define `TestLambda` class. But theres a few things to watch out for.

1. `executeAround` will need variants depending on return values etc.
2. Your `TestLambda` definition needs to throw exceptions. (Which the standard Java 8 lambdas do not.)
3. It's a bad practice to just swallow exceptions.

```
public static class Test {
    public void a() {
       executeAround( ()->{ do_something ; } );
    }
    public void b() {
       executeAround( ()->{ do_something_else; } );
    }

    private void executeAround( TestLambda fn ) {
       try {
          fn();
       } catch( Exception e) {
          logger.error("error happened");
       }
    } 
 }
```

Comment: it looks good. do you know how can i do this with an annotation?

Answer (score 0):

You **could** use a java.lang.reflect.Proxy to solve this kind of problem but should be sure whether you really want to do this. 
Since you are working with reflection here, which is much less performant and you would have to create additional classes and interfaces, this solution is only really practicable in very few use cases.

First of all you'll need a interface to be proxied:

```
public interface YourInterface {
    void a();
    void b();
}
```

This interface then have to be implemented by your class:

```
public class YourClass implements YourInterface {
    public void a() {}
    public void b() {}
}
```

The class which will do the common exception handling has to be an InvocationHandler. This class could be a general implementation and could be used for different target classes:

```
public static class ExceptionHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private final Map<String, Method> methods = new HashMap<>();

    private Object target;

    public ExceptionHandler(Object target) {
        this.target = target;

        for(Method method: target.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
            this.methods.put(method.getName(), method);
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return this.methods.get(method.getName()).invoke(this.target, args);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // do common handling here
        }
    }
}
```

You could then use all this like that:

```
YourClass yourObj = new YourClass();

YourInterface yourProxy = (YourInterface) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            YourInterface.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{YourInterface.class}, new ExceptionHandler(yourObj));

yourProxy.a();
```

As you see your object instatioation will differ but the methods will be used as you would do it usually.
In this case, the method is processed by the InvocationHandler, which delegates the call to your actual object. However, if an exception occurs, it first lands in the invoke method of the InvocationHandler and can be handled there.